# Laravel Searching with Pagination?

Tags: search, laravel-5.7, laravel-pagination

I've been trying so hard to get this but I couldn't. Searching is all working fine also **pagination is appearing**, but whenever I click on any page number is opens a **blank page** since there is no route to "GET" that request, can anyone please lead to some place where I can find how to show other pages with a searching query or do I have to create get route to show other pages? I'm all confused what to do?

Tried With GET method Still, not working

Route

```
Route::get('search/','Coins@search')->name('coin.search');
```

Controller

```
public function search(){
        $keyword = Input::get('search');
        if($keyword){
            $result = [];
            $resultByName = Coin::
                                where('type','=','coin')
                                ->where('parent_id','=',0)
                                ->where('coin_name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
                                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                                ->paginate(10);
            $resultByDescription = Coin::where('type','=','coin')
                ->where('parent_id','=',0)
                ->where('description','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
                ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->paginate(10);
            if($resultByName->count()) {
                $result =  $resultByName;
                $message = "Coin Detail found in coin name !! based on searching data : ".$keyword;
            }else{
                if($resultByDescription->count()){
                    $result =  $resultByDescription;
                    $message = "Coin Detail found in description !! based on searching data : ".$keyword;
                }else{
                    $result = Coin::where('type','=','coin')->where('parent_id','=',0)->get();
                    $message = "No Coin Found !! based on searching data : ".$keyword;
                }
            }
            return view($this->layout.'coins')->with([
                'allCoins' => $result,
                'message'  => $message
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Blade

```
  {!! Form::open([
                    'route'   => 'coin.search'
                    ,'method' => 'GET'
                    ,'id'     => 'coinSearch'])
   !!}
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search Your Coin Here . . . " name="search">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Search</button>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
{!! $allCoins->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the appends method on the result object returned by the paginate query. It accepts an array as a parameter and in the array, you can specify as many variables as you want.

```
  $results->appends ();
```

Such as one of your query will become

```
$resultByName = Coin::where('type','=','coin')
                 ->where('parent_id','=',0)
                 ->where('coin_name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
                 ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                 ->paginate(10);
 $resultByName->appends (array ('keyword' => $keyword));
```

It will append all the variables in the link and your URL will become

```
http://your_domain/search?keyword=$keyword(value of this variable)
```

Pagination will work without adding any custom code.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I get the value in URL in my controller? like keyword=anything

Comment: Okay i'm sooooo dumb, i wasted my two days for this, i'm accepting this but my real problem was i had to shift my route before all other route contains coins in name and in url, but reallly thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination only works with GET parameters. You should use GET method for your search and pagination.

POST requests are not for the purpose of displaying data. Why? There are many reasons.

I suggest you change your route type to GET and your search form method to GET.

Comment: You mean like this ? Route::get('coin/search/{searchingValue}', ['uses' => 'Coins@search'])->name('coin.search');

Comment: @ViperTecPro yeah that's the route. now test it and let know if you if you face any issue

Comment: Sorry i don't understand and i tried to change form to get also route but it's not working :(, can you please provide me code

Comment: @ViperTecPro what's not working?  pagination or search with pagination?

Comment: It's showing blank now this is in my url coin/search?search=test and it's not even calling controller, i already cleared caches

Comment: Route::get('search','Coins@search')->name('coin.search'); there is no need for parameters

Comment: Still it showing blank page, it's not even calling controller function how am i suppose to debug that

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved this problem not all by myself obviously, but all i had to do is reconfigure my route like this

```
 Route::get('coin/search/{keyword?}', ['uses' => 'Coins@doSearch'])->name('coin.search');
 Route::resource('coin' , 'Coins');
```